# How to install ruber header files on mac os?

Tags: ruby, macos

I try to install cocoapods on macos using this command:

`sudo gem install cocoapods`

I got the following error:

```
ERROR:  Error installing cocoapods:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    current directory: /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/ffi-1.12.2/ext/ffi_c
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/bin/ruby -I /Library/Ruby/Site/2.3.0 -r ./siteconf20200309-67350-e0q2jt.rb extconf.rb
mkmf.rb can't find header files for ruby at /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/lib/ruby/include/ruby.h

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/ffi-1.12.2 for inspection.
Results logged to /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/extensions/universal-darwin-18/2.3.0/ffi-1.12.2/gem_make.out
```

I've already installed `rbenv` and ruby version 2.3.0.

Comment: Don't use sudo if you're trying to use rbenv. Note that the errors you see are referencing the system version of Ruby, not the rbenv version of Ruby, so double check that you have properly installed rbenv.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Do you know how to install ruby-2.0-dev globaly and without using `rbenv`? I think that would solve my probiem. Can't find any brew package.

Comment: Ignore the answer by GosuGod. That references Linux, not macOS. So no, it won't solve the problem. To solve your problem, search stackoverflow. This has been asked and answered many times.

Answer (score 0):

I found some documentation for **cocoapods** and problems of that gem: [link](https://guides.cocoapods.org/using/troubleshooting#installing-cocoapods)

From your error log i found this:

> `mkmf.rb can't find header files for ruby at`

For install this gem you need **ruby2.0-dev package**, try first install ***it***, and ***after that*** try again to install cocoapods. (I found this info from that [link](https://github.com/brightbox/deb-ruby2.0/issues/1))

Comment: I did rbenv install ruby2.3.0-dev and also ruby2.0-dev wihch doesn't solve the problem. `/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0` still can not be found.

Comment: As you see - you trying to install gems inside system gem directory. For example i have gems in this directory: `/home/$USER/.rbenv/shims/gem `(linux system). Try to use this commands (if you're really installed rbenv as ruby version manager): `rbenv global 2.3.0` and `rbenv local 2.3.0`. Maybe this will solve your problem. And of course do not use `sudo` if you want to install gem. Gems should be installed without sudo.